# Original sanskrit texts

Tags: ramayana, mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, sanskrit

I am looking for original Sanskrit texts of the Mahabharata, Ramayana and Bhagavad Gita. Is it possible to find scanned versions of these texts online?

Comment: What do you mean by original and scanned? In the ancient times people used to scribe on palm leaves and eventually it came into modern print forms. Most of the Gitas around have Sanskrit text in tact with very insignificant variations. Mahabharata is said to be altered so versions may vary. And Ramayana being much older may have many alternate readings.

Comment: @srinivasacaryadasa I am looking for the oldest available version of these texts.

Comment: Well for Gita pretty much any sampradaya can provide one with the original sanskrit. You can get  one here http://www.bhagavatgita.ru/files/Bhagavad-gita_As_It_Is.pdf For Ramayan and Mahabharat you can see http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ and http://www.sacred-texts.com/ but I am not sure of what sampradaya the authors belong to and how authentically it was transmitted down.

Comment: If by the word "original" you mean exactly what I suppose, then unfortunately you can not find any. What you see around is all tempered, fiddled text. Appending "as-it-is" to a text's name doesn't make it original. So you should aim to find, the OLDEST text available for the titles mentioned. But still for that you may need to dig at British libraries, Or Vatican Secret library, I guess. In India you won't find anything older than 200 yrs. Remember **India was under foreign (Anti-Hindu) rule for >800 years**. So Truth is now fragmented.

Comment: BTW Hinduism is NEVER supposed to be on paper, in the first place. So the word "Original" used with 'Text', in itself doesn't makes sense here.

Comment: @Adhvaitha Indeed University of Nalanda, Taxila, Ujjain, are ALL Lost. Not to mention that Nalanda was raided three time by those illiterate Muslim barbarians. And whatever was left has been poisoned with stupidity, and obscenity by Catholic Victorian Historians. I myself am searching for any scripture >200 years before 1900, because that should be LESS corrupt. You may start from ASI Library's digitized books list http://asi.nic.in/pdf_data/asi_library_digitized_books.pdf , here I couldn't find anything useful. You may also search http://sanskritdocuments.org too.

Comment: Check the "Major Works" link at [Sanskrit documents](http://www.sanskritdocuments.org)

Answer (score 5):

The original Sanskrit version of the Bhagavadgita is not hard to find: just look on [bhagavad-gita.org](http://bhagavad-gita.org).

The Sanskrit version of the Mahabharata (the BORI critical edition, which is probably the most accurate version) can be found here:

- [Book 1](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-01.pdf)
- [Book 2](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-02.pdf)
- [Book 3](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-03.pdf)
- [Book 4](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-04.pdf)
- [Book 5](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-05.pdf)
- [Book 6](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-06.pdf)
- [Book 7](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-07.pdf)
- [Book 8](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-08.pdf)
- [Book 9](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-09.pdf)
- [Book 10](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-10.pdf)
- [Book 11](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-11.pdf)
- [Book 12](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-12.pdf)
- [Book 13](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-13.pdf)
- [Book 14](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-14.pdf)
- [Book 15](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-15.pdf)
- [Book 16](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-16.pdf)
- [Book 17](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-17.pdf)
- [Book 18](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-18.pdf)

Sacred-texts.com has the same BORI critical edition of the Mahabharata [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/index.htm) but with a Roman transliteration. Actually, it also has the Devanagari, but there are several rendering issues, so I recommend you use the PDFs above for the Devanagari and sacred-texts.com for the transliteration if you need it.

As for the Ramayana: [this website](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/ramayana/valmiki.htm) has the Baroda critical edition (again, the most accurate version of the Ramayana that I know of). Simply enter the book (kanda) and the chapter at the very bottom of the webpage, and it will give you the entire chapter. You can even change from the Devanagari version and change it to a Roman transliteration.

It's important to note that with the Ramayana and Mahabharata, there is no such thing as the "original" version. There are several recensions, but both have critical editions that are the most accurate versions, for which I have given links.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lot of original scanned versions in the following site.

https://archive.org/details/texts

Comment: Instead of just providing Internet Archive link, you should provide links specifically for the Scriptures mentioned in the question.